# Why is my json file not found?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, google-chrome-devtools

I have a json file in a Content folder within my asp.net project:

```
<projectName>
    \Content
        NBCCJr.json
```

...and the code to access it:

```
$.getJSON('~/Content/NBCCJr.json', function (data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, dataPoint) {
        // Bla
      });
  });
)
```

...but nothing happens when the code is called; the browser console says, "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Why is it not found? Isn't "tilde whack filename" the correct route to the file?

### UPDATE

I also tried it with the "whacks" backwards:

```
$.getJSON('~\Content\NBCCJr.json', function (data) {
```

...and got the same result ("*Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)*")

### UPDATE 2

Then I tried it sans a prepended whack thusly:

```
$.getJSON('Content/NBCCJr.json', function (data) {
```

...and I get this ambiguous message in the console:

```
*GET http://localhost:9702/Content/NBCCJr.json 404 (Not Found) jquery.js:8724
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost:9702/Content/NBCCJr.json".*
```

So it was not found and yet loaded anyway?

### UPDATE 3

When I attempted to navigate to the file in the browser by changing:

```
http://localhost:9702/Default.cshtml
```

...to:

```
http://localhost:9702/Content/NBCCJr.json
```

I got an informative WSOD message from Vint Cerf, Tim Berners-Lee, and/or Al Gore saying:

*HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.*

### UPDATE 4

Thanks to JAM, it is now working.

I had to add this to Web.Config:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Don't worry about the code for now, see if you can locate the file in your browser to start with

Comment: I've commented out all the code after the line shown, for that reason. IOW, the function is empty.

Comment: Did you manage to show the json in your browser? i.e. putting the URL directly into the address bar?

Comment: @greg: What did it "clench"?

Comment: I was having this problem. I tried methods in jquery and d3. Adding the mime section got me going. I was really stumped. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Update 4 solved for me! Thks \o/

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Have you tried removing the `~` ?

As in:

```
$.getJSON('/Content/dumboJr.json', function (data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, dataPoint) {
        // Bla
      });
  });
)
```

To allow the IIS to serve JSON files, try adding this to your web.config:

```
<staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
</staticContent>
```

Comment: Yes (now I have). This:
$.getJSON('/Content/NBCCJr.json', function (data) {
gives the same response.

Comment: Is it a 404 response? Have you tried navigating to the file directly in your browser? Is the Content folder in the root of your web project?

Comment: Yes, the post says that. Please see my updates. Yes, Content is a first-level folder, as indicated in the original post.

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158193/how-to-allow-download-of-json-file-with-asp-net).

Comment: If you add the specified web.config mime type you will be fine :)

Comment: If you add this via the iis management console, be sure to restart your application to see the changes.

Comment: Thanks! also check this for web.config ref... http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent

Comment: When I disable CORS of the browser and configure the Web.config like @Stefan is recommending on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19517275/1732989) everything is working for me

Answer (score 22):

## Solution is you need to add json file extension type in MIME Types

#### Method 1

**Go to IIS, Select your application and Find MIME Types**

[image]

**Click on Add from Right panel**

File Name Extension = .json

MIME Type = application/json

[image]

After adding **.json** file type in **MIME Types**, **Restart IIS** and try to access json file

---

#### Method 2

Go to web.config of that application and add this lines in it

```
 <system.webServer>
   <staticContent>
     <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
   </staticContent>
 </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the *.json file in the webRoot, not in a sub folder. And then reference it like:

```
$.getJSON('NBCCJr.json', function (data) {
```

This of course requires the previous inclusion and instantiation of the jQuery system object from: **jquery.min.js** or the JSON structure from: **json2-1.0.min.js**

Answer (score 1):

I Changed .json to .txt and request is working fine. I am not sure about the consequence .txt can cause.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `ASP.NET Core`, just put the file in `wwwroot` but if you use `ASP.NET` framework, this allows JSON extension from web.config as follows:

```
<staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
</staticContent>
```

and

```
<location path="Content">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```