# Allow loading of JSON files in Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2013

I have the problem, that the IIS from Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web doesn't allow the loading of *.json files. When trying to load a *.json file I get a 403 Forbidden and a help page how to configure the IIS allow the loading of JSON files, but don't know what to do with this information / where the IIS is even located.

This is the error page:

> HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found The page you are requesting cannot be
>   served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a
>   script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME
>   map.
>
> Most likely causes: It is possible that a handler mapping is missing.
>   By default, the static file handler processes all content. The feature
>   you are trying to use may not be installed. The appropriate MIME map
>   is not enabled for the Web site or application. (Warning: Do not
>   create a MIME map for content that users should not download, such as
>   .ASPX pages or .config files.) If ASP.NET is not installed.
>
> Things you can try: In system.webServer/handlers: Ensure that the
>   expected handler for the current page is mapped. Pay extra attention
>   to preconditions (for example, runtimeVersion, pipelineMode, bitness)
>   and compare them to the settings for your application pool. Pay extra
>   attention to typographical errors in the expected handler line. Please
>   verify that the feature you are trying to use is installed. Verify
>   that the MIME map is enabled or add the MIME map for the Web site
>   using the command-line tool appcmd.exe. To set a MIME type, run the
>   following command in the IIS Express install directory: appcmd set
>   config /section:staticContent
>   /+[fileExtension='string',mimeType='string'] The variable
>   fileExtension string is the file name extension and the variable
>   mimeType string is the file type description. For example, to add a
>   MIME map for a file which has the extension ".xyz": appcmd set config
>   /section:staticContent /+[fileExtension='.xyz',mimeType='text/plain']
>   Warning: Ensure that this MIME mapping is needed for your Web server
>   before adding it to the list. Configuration files such as .CONFIG or
>   dynamic scripting pages such as .ASP or .ASPX, should not be
>   downloaded directly and should always be processed through a handler.
>   Other files such as database files or those used to store
>   configuration, like .XML or .MDF, are sometimes used to store
>   configuration information. Determine if clients can download these
>   file types before enabling them. Install ASP.NET. Check the failed
>   request tracing logs for additional information about this error. For
>   more information, click here.
>
> Detailed Error Information: Module       StaticFileModule Notification
>   ExecuteRequestHandler Handler    StaticFile Error Code       0x80070032
>   Requested URL    http: //localhost:64107/Settings/Settings.json
>   Physical Path    D:\GIT\RepoP_Paneon\Settings\Settings.json Logon
>   Method       Anonymous Logon User    Anonymous Request Tracing Directory
>   C:\Users\stefank\Documents\IISExpress\TraceLogFiles\REPOP_PANEON
>
> More Information: This error occurs when the file extension of the
>   requested URL is for a MIME type that is not configured on the server.
>   You can add a MIME type for the file extension for files that are not
>   dynamic scripting pages, database, or configuration files. Process
>   those file types using a handler. You should not allows direct
>   downloads of dynamic scripting pages, database or configuration files.
>   View more information »

Answer (score 170, accepted):

After some more googling, and experimenting I found out, that you have to define IIS settings in the `Web.config`.

After adding the following configuration:

```xml
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
```

it works like a charm.

Full setup file example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Interesting, this didn't work for me. I'm using VS 2013, IIS Express, IE 11, .NET 4.5.1.

Comment: how does your config file look?

Comment: This didn't work for me neither. .json file is still served as html/text MIME type

Comment: I had to add `<remove fileExtension=".json" />` before the mimeMap.

Answer (score 14):

Better add remove tag in case future IIS has build in json support. This is my web.config section of mimeMap.

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <remove fileExtension=".json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
  </staticContent>
<system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 6):

- Open CMD with administrator privilages.
- Go to:

  `cd C:\Program Files\IIS Express`
  or
  `cd C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express`
- Run command:

  `appcmd set config /section:staticContent /+[fileExtension='JSON',mimeType='application/x-javascript']`

Answer (score 6):

We may need to distinguish the Visual Studio development environment (with IIS Express) from local IIS and a remote server (like Azure WebSites). To specifically target IIS Express, for example, we edit `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config` under `system.webServer/staticContent`:

```
<mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/javascript" />
```

I need to make this distinction because my local (intranet) IIS already has the JSON mime type defined. So when I deploy to Azure websites I use this transformation in `Web.Release.config`:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/javascript" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```