# JSON file cannot be found in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am attempting to load a JSON file from javascript but i keep getting the following error even though the path is correct

```
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 2ms]
```

this is the code i am using to load it

```
loadJSON(callback) {
    var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    xobj.open('GET', 'Assets/test.json', true); // Replace 'my_data' with the path to your file
    xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == 200) {
            // Required use of an anonymous callback as .open will NOT return a value but simply returns undefined in asynchronous mode
            callback(xobj.responseText);
        }
    };
    xobj.send(null);
}

window.onload = function () {
var canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.getElementById('Can');
context = canvas.getContext('2d');

load = new preload.AtlasLoader();
load.loadJSON(init);


}

function init(response) {
    image2 = JSON.parse(response);
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: If you're getting a 404, then the address cannot be correct. Either it's wrong in your JavaScript code, or the server has the file in the wrong place.

Comment: Obviously your path is not correct - that's what 404 means. Perhaps you are missing leading `/`? Some browsers will interpret your URL as "add `Assets/test.json` to current location". Try `/Assets/test.json`.

Comment: You can see more about the issued query in the network tab of your browser's developer tools.

Comment: Are you definitely able to view the file itself in your browser? Maybe try adding `../` to the beginning of your location URL, or just a `/`? If you can access it directly in the browser, try adding the full direct URL into the JS code, and see what that says? Then you'll know it's something to do with your relative URL.

Comment: It's also possible that your server is not configured to deliver files with the `.json` extension with the `application/json` MIME type.

Comment: i am using visual studio to load the file, could the issue be with the IIS? EDIT: I realized it was a configuration issue with IIS and i googled it and found it.

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer in this thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516829/allow-loading-of-json-files-in-visual-studio-express-2013-for-web

it was a configuration issue with IIS and you just need to add the lnes posted in the answer in that question.