# Reading Json file from angularJs causing error

Tags: json, angularjs, iis-7

I am trying to read a json file from my visual studio 2013 environment. It is throwing some error as mentioned below

**`The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.`**

However its working fine on `plnkr` http://plnkr.co/edit/std1ngB40YIJBmC94Zdm?p=preview

Can someone please let me know how to resolve the same ?

Error screen shot

[image]

**Folder Structure** 
[image]

[image]

Comment: so is there a file of that name in root of site? We can't debug path problems from an image alone. Also error message seems like you may need to configure IIS for json files

Comment: yes I am reading the file from that path

Comment: Guys, I didn't understand for negative voting ????

Comment: How can that be if you are getting a 404? Comment doesn't make sense and isn't very informative with regard to troubleshooting

Comment: I have added one more image of my folder structure. hoping it will give you more clarity.
You can see that ``employees.json`` is at root

Comment: Then you need to configure IIS to allow json. Should be easy to research

Comment: did you try change extension to `js`?

Comment: No, because I thought its json file so extension should be .json right ?

Comment: Have you added a mine map for the file extension, as it suggests?

Comment: json isn't executable. Problem is related to mime extensions allowed in IIS. Again, do some research. Changing extension to js would work just to test, both are static resources

Comment: @JamesTrotter : yes i have already added MIME Type

Comment: @charlietfl : yes ``.js`` is fine but it should work with ``json`` as well because already working on ``plnkr`` so doing R&D on the same

Comment: plunker has nothing to do with your server not delivering a json file due to mime type issue. Your problem has nothing to do with javascript or client side

Comment: Hi Guys :-)

Its fixed now, please refer the answer as mentioned below..Feeling relaxed and happy finally :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I done lot of research on this issue and finally its resolved :) :)

I tried the answer given by @James Trotter as well but didn't get success.

I don't know why MIME in IIS didn't work but it worked when I added it in web.config

**SOLUTION :**

```
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
```

**For More Information**

[Allow loading of JSON files in Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516829/allow-loading-of-json-files-in-visual-studio-express-2013-for-web)

Answer (score -1):

Have you set up the mime map correctly? I only see a screenshot for the handler mapping.

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Display properties for the IIS Server
3. Click MIME Types and then add the JSON extension:

   - File name extension: .json MIME
   - type: application/json
4. Go back to the properties for IIS Server
5. Click on Handler Mappings
6. Add a script map

   - Request path: *.json
   - Executable: C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll
   - Name: JSON

If this still fails to work remove the script map completed and just stick with the mime map, I do not know why you are adding the script map in the first place.

Comment: Please read the error carefully , you can see that ``If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.``

Comment: @Gaurvav but the page is not a script? you are doing a `$http.get`which means the client is **downloading** the file not the server **executing** the file. Therefore, you need to set up a mime type so that the **download** request is correctly handled by the server. Follow my advice. **handler mappings** handle **server executable code**, **mime mappings** handle non-executable content usually streamed to the client. I believe it is you who needs to read the error correctly, this is a download. Not a script.

Comment: I got your point and tried the same steps as you said but it didn't work. Do you have any idea what am I missing ?