# 404 Error while trying access JSON file using D3 Framework

Tags: javascript, json, web, d3.js, http-status-code-404

Hi so i'm in the middle of learning the D3 Framework, but no matter what I do, I can't seem to load my Json file.  I'm running the script on a server and the JSON file is in the same directory as the html/d3 file im running it from but it keeps giving me a 404 error when I look at the console.

So Im running it on www.mywebsite.com, and then I have the Json file stored in www.mywebsite.com/mydata.json
Can anyone help me out?

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    d3.json("mydata.json", function(data){ 

        var canvas= d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width",500)
        .attr("height", 500)

        canvas.selectAll("rect")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("width", function(d){ return d.age *10;})
                .attr("height", 50)
                .attr("y", function(d ,i){ return i* 50; })
                .attr("fill", "blue");
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: Are this html file and mydata.json in the same directory?

Comment: Yeah both locally and on the server, im pretty sure the problem is that the JSON file that I wrote is being saved as a text/html file.  I saved it as mydata.json but because I wrote it in sublime 2 i think there was a problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://www.sencha.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-231245.html?s=b3ded91de8f0d30560c9b993a38c1f68) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17626776/why-is-my-json-file-not-found) gotchas. Let us know if you succeeded accessing json after that.

Comment: So I followed the advice of one of the guides, I poked around the debugger and it turns out my JSON file is being saved as Text/html even though im giving it the mydata.json file type.  I wrote it in sublime 2, do you know any fixes to this?

Comment: The fix is either your file will be of appropriate json type or you just rename *.json to *.txt. I wouldn't bother finding root cause why Sublime Text 2 or any other editor saved your json as text/html type, and I think neither should you... :) The most important thing is: can you display data on your web page?

Comment: So instead of d3.json("mydata.json", function(data){ I should save as txt and put d3.json("mydata.txt", function(data)?  I doubt my text editor is the problem im just confused on how to get it in the right format.  Thanks for the help

Comment: I have no idea why that was the solution but it worked!  Thanks so much, if you have a moment do you know why saving it as a text file allowed the JSON to be found?

Answer (score 1):

You guys need not change any Formats. Just need to change some settings in Server.Here I am using IIS server so I have tested my files and got same 404 error for JSON Files and I made the following changes and it worked like a Charm. You just follow this If you are using an IIS Server...

Step 1: Open IIS Server and go to MIME Types

[image]

Step2: Click Add from right side and add JSON extension and restart the server

[image]