# Getting error when trying to use translation using angular-translate

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

In my application i am trying to use localization featrure and for that I am using angular-translate.js . When I am trying to configure the translation using a static JSON file , I am getting the error couldnot

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  http://mydomain.com/JsonFiles/locale-en.json

I have written the below code for using translation feature from a JSON file.

```
$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
    prefix: 'JsonFiles/locale-',
    suffix: '.json'
});
```

But it is giving error . Please tell me where I have made the mistake.

Thanks
Utpal

Comment: What don't you undrstand in the message? It can't find the json file at the URL  http://mydomain.com/JsonFiles/locale-en.json. So, make sure it's there.

Comment: @JB Nizet in my project folder I have added the file but the error is still showing.Even the demo application which I have downloaded from plunker giving same error.Please suggest what I have made wrong.

Comment: It depends on what your web server is, how it is configured, where the files are located. It doesn't have much to do with AngularJS

Comment: @JB Nizet I am not yet hosted it any webserver and I am developing it in my local development area. Currently it is running in my local domain.Is there any way to run this in my local development area.Because as per the example given in the plunker it should run

Comment: Of course. You are running a web server on your local mahine to serve the files over HTTP. The nature and configuration of that local web server is what matters.

Comment: @JB Nizet then what are the option to configure the webserver . I am running my project using visual studio and I guess it is using the IIS as default webserver.

Comment: I don't know anything about IIS.

Answer (score 1):

If it still relevant...
I had this problem with IIS web server, by default it doesn't support *.json extension.
See this question:
[How to allow download of .json file with ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158193/how-to-allow-download-of-json-file-with-asp-net)