# Working with a static .json file located in App_Data?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-4

In my ASP.NET MVC 4 project, I have a `.json` file in my `App_Data` folder containing geographical data that I want to load up into D3.js.

So far, my working approach has been to have jQuery perform an AJAX call to some Controller which returns a JsonResult - and on success, storing the JSON in some Javascript variable which gets loaded into D3.  This time around, I'd like to skip the controller and request a static `.json` file directly from the App_Data folder instead.

I tried grabbing the .json's relative path using `var url = "@Url.Content("~/App_Data/example.json")";`, but the Javascript debugger excoriated me with lots of weird regex errors.

I also tried throwing the file into the Content folder to see if the directory name makes a difference.

- `var path = "@Url.Content("~/Content/example.json")";` resulted in

  > NetworkError: 404 Not Found - localhost:xxxxx/Content/u.json
- `var path = @Url.Content("~/Content/example.json");` resulted in

  > SyntaxError: invalid regular expression flag u: var path = /Content/example.json;
- `var json = $.getJSON("../Content/example.json")` appears to send a request to the correct directory, but returns a 404 error.  Additionally, using Razor syntax to point to the relative URL works, but still 404s.
- [Adding mimeMap info to web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158193/how-to-allow-download-of-json-file-with-asp-net) also didn't help.

My question is: is it possible to work with a JSON file stored in `App_Data` (or the `Content` directory), using *only* Javascript/jQuery?  In ASP.NET, is there only *one* way to do this?  Is there a better approach to take altogether?

Comment: You cannot access any `App_*` folders from outside the server for security reasons.  You'll have to move it somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was being caused by a [problem with IIS Express](http://forums.asp.net/t/1701795.aspx?Which+folder+should+json+file+be+placed+in+), and [this post helped me resolve the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18387874/3474146).  I navigated to

```
C:\Users\<username>\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config
```

and added

```
<mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
```

to the `<staticContent>` section in *there*.  It wasn't sufficient to add that line to web.config.  So it *is* possible to work with a static .json file stored in the ../Content folder.

Comment: there is problem in your mimeMap don't use dot use it as follows   <mimeMap fileExtension="json" mimeType="application/json" /> can you see there is not dot with  fileExtension="json"

Comment: No, dude.  This is what the IIS Express <staticContent> config looks like by default: `<mimeMap fileExtension=".323" mimeType="text/h323" />`, `<mimeMap fileExtension=".3g2" mimeType="video/3gpp2" />`, `<mimeMap fileExtension=".3gp2" mimeType="video/3gpp2" />`, ...

Comment: Ok ,for me my solution the way i described worked anyhow I am happy that you have solved it.thank you

Answer (score 11):

To read json files in visual studio first you need to use following in your web.config

you can use it anywhere in

```
<configuration>
      <system.webServer>
       <staticContent>  
          <mimeMap fileExtension="json" mimeType="application/json" />
       </staticContent>
     </system.webServer>
      -------All other Settings---
      ----Your all other setting------
</configuration>
```

App_Data cann't be accessed due to security restrictions but you can place your file somewhere else in you application.try doing it by using jquery function getJSON() below is an example.

```
      $("document").ready(function() {

    var jqxhr = $.getJSON("/Content/usa.json", function () {
        console.log("success");
    })
   .done(function () {
       console.log("second success");
   })
   .fail(function () {
       console.log("error");
   })
   .always(function () {
       console.log("complete");
   });
});
```

Happy Coding Enjoy

Comment: Granted, I should not store the .json in App_Data.  However, storing it in the Content directory fails when I attempt to use this approach: `var json = $.getJSON("../Content/usa.json", function () { console.log(json); });` yields `"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:61103/Content/usa.json"`.

Comment: Read my entire answer again I have edited it and you will get success.I prepared a demo application to solve your problem and i got success in it.

Comment: I very much appreciate your help, but this did not work for me, and I researched/answered my own question below.  The problem is with IISExpress.  Adding the <staticContent> bit to Web.config did not work: I had to travel further, all the way into the IIS config, and change the mime settings there.  Without doing this, the `$.getJSON` attempt 404s.

Comment: you have problem because you are using   .(dot) symbol in you mime type plz don't use this .(dot).I test demo app with dot it did not worked then i removed dot and it worked perfectly fine for me.I can send you demo if you want.but plz first remove .(dot) and give it try again

Comment: use as follows  <mimeMap fileExtension="json" mimeType="application/json" />  can you see not dot with file extension

Comment: Thanks @Husrat, maybe I'll do this instead next time.  I resolved the issue completely [in the way I describe here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25163606/3474146), even with the '.' in '.json'.

Answer (score 1):

"exoriated me with lots of weird regex errors and other stuff" - more details might be needed there.

Did you try to use Razor syntax in a plain javascript file? Razor syntax only works in cshtml files.

A second guess of mine would be that `App_Data` is not served by the web server. This would be a huge security gap - any user could simply download your database files from that folder. If you want to make it available statically, put it in `Scripts/` or `Content/`.

Comment: I edited the question to show my previous approach which used the Content directory instead of App_Data, but as none of those attempts were successful, I am merely asking if what I am trying to do is possible before I move on to a different approach altogether (the MVC controller approach).

Answer (score 0):

For static data simply assign the data to a variable in a js file and put it in page as `<script>` tag. Pass that variable to your initialization method(s)

Comment: Technically I *could* just copy and paste the .json into the script, but I want to store the .json in the Content folder instead because it's a pretty big file, and I feel like the code would be messy.  This is an appropriate answer to my question that is admittedly broad, but my problem is precisely with assigning the (external) data to a variable in a .js file.