# Path of topojson not drawn in browser

Tags: d3.js, geojson, topojson

I want to display a map with d3 but the path is not drawn in the browser although in the developer tools I see that the topojson file is loaded so there is data for the path. I just get a blank page. What could be the problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
height = 600;

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(null);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

d3.json("build/immoscout.topojson", function(error, us) {
  if (error) return console.error(error);

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(us))
      .attr("d", path);
});
```

Comment: You need to set a projection.

Comment: You are calling `.projection(null)`. You need to set one of D3's projections there.

Answer (score 1):

Is your question answered based on Lars' comment, "You are calling .projection(null). You need to set one of D3's projections there"? Few projection options listed below. You may also want to check and make sure that your server can run .topojson files. See [How to allow download of .json file with ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158193/how-to-allow-download-of-json-file-with-asp-net)

- Extension: .json
- MIME type: application/json

---

- Extension: .geojson
- MIME type: application/json

---

- Extension: .topojson
- MIME type: application/json

1) Mollweide projection shows the entire world

```
var width = 500;
var height = 500;
var projection = d3.geo.mollweide()
    .scale(120)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);
var geoPath = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);
```

2) Mercator projection, which has became standard used by Google Maps

```
var width = 500;
var height = 500;
var aProjection = d3.geo.mercator()
        .scale(80)//80 works well in this case
        .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);
var geoPath = d3.geo.path().projection(aProjection);//d3.geo.path() defaults to albersUSA, which is a projection suitable only for maps of the United States
```

`