# give relative path in javascript file in asp.net folder

Tags: javascript, asp.net, d3.js

I am trying to use a relative path in JavaScript to get a JSON file which is placed in my asp.net folder structure. To get the file I am using `d3.json()`. I have used below code

```
d3.json("../Resources/flare.json", function (error, root) {
...some code;
});
```

Here is my directory structure:

[image: directory structure]

Unfortunately, this is not working.

> I am getting error :Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: Is `flare.jsonson` a typo?

Comment: your directive structure?

Comment: yes. Its a .json file.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Is the `error` parameter `null`? If not, what's in it? Are there any errors on the console?

Comment: [Have you configured your application to serve static JSON files?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10575356/16363)