# Files and folders in File Manager are not displayed in Roxy file manager in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file, file-manager, roxy-fileman

I project myself that I used the MVC used for managing files from Roxy File Manager! Everything is correct and complete project works!
My problem is when the server I'm Publish project was a project file, but the file does not show !!!!! I do not know where is the problem?
I "main.ashx" settings is as follows got the "GetFilesRoot"

```
ret = _context.Server.MapPath("/Uploads/Web");
```

This is when the host is not the answer! I also tried different ways !!

With ~ no ~

With . . Without . .

First /

The first / deleted

Just put ~

I tried every way I knew it was not OK, but that was not

[It's my system files run the show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtIZY.jpg)

[It does not run on the server where the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4Koq.jpg)

Comment: Start with the root of your site with `~` and specify the full path: `~/Uploads/Web`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your web server doesn't know how to serve `.json` files.

- Open IIS Manager.
- Display properties for the IIS Server.
- Click MIME Types and then add the JSON extension: File name extension: `.json` and MIME type: `application/json`

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158193/how-to-allow-download-of-json-file-with-asp-net)