# manifest.json validation error (confirmed manifest.json is valid)

Tags: manifest, manifest.json

I'm getting the following error with my manifest.json:

`Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token.`

I've confirmed my manifest.json is valid and is encoded in UTF-8. Can anyone give me any tips on what might be causing this issue?

Comment: Well, please provide some context, i have no idea exactly where you want to use it. Jyst in case you want to use it inside a pwa, i once ha that error too, and it was because my server didnt actually server the right file. Try manually typing the path to it in the browser to see of you get it

Comment: I setup a route in express to serve the manifest.json file...still no dice

Comment: First, sorry for the typos, sceond, can you send me the full code of the route?

Comment: Maybe you should add web.config file to your build folder
here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12378712/loading-json-files-generates-404-errors

Answer (score 1):

Is this an Angular project?
And are you trying to host this on Azure?
I had the same error, i posted my fix here:

[Angular 6 application : Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54127634/angular-6-application-manifest-line-1-column-1-unexpected-token)

If this is not related to Azure, but it is an Angular project, check your angular.json/angular-cli.json and add manifest.json to "assets" as described by Honzik in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51553047/7335211

Comment: It's not an Angular project, I'm using Polymer (for work). Thanks for the look, I'll check out the link.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to put a comma "," 
Valid example:

```
{
   "manifest_version": 2, <<comma
   "version": "1.0", <<comma
   "name": "my extension name" <<no comma
}
```

Invalid example:

```
{
   "manifest_version": 2 << no comma
   "version": "1.0" <<no comma
   "name": "my extension name" <<no comma
}
```

Or you only forgot to put ", or ":"