# When build the app: GET http://localhost ......json 404 (Not Found)

Tags: reactjs, iis

I have my App react (create-app-react...) My app access to file .json in the folder assets. In my test in local no problem but when publish in IIS (npm run build) can't access a this file .json, in console obtain this error: GET http://localhost:3700/assets/locales/en/isotope.json 404 (Not Found).

My structure app ...
    assets
       locales
          es
            isotope.json 
    static
       css
       js
    index.html
    ...

Can you help me??

Comment: could you share which path you set in code? and make sure that you properly host ReactJS in IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to manually copy the resources that are not added via `require` or `import`. Make sure you have assets folder in the site root on the server.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was not having included in the MIME Types (IIS) the .json.
Now Work It!!!

Thanks

Comment: Perfect!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158193/how-to-allow-download-of-json-file-with-asp-net